# PostgreSQL - NULL References

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I have a data model for Tasks and Equipments.

Sometimes a `Task` needs some `Equipment` to be completed, sometimes it doesn't.

Task table

```
create table task (
    id serial primary key
,   task_name varchar(80)
)
```

Equipment table

```
 create table equipment (
        id serial primary key
    ,   equipment_name varchar(80)
    )
```

What I would like to do is add a null reference to the `Task table`.

```
create table task (
    id serial primary key
,   task_name varchar(80)
,   equipment_id serial null references equipment(id) 
)
```

I get an error

```
ERROR:  conflicting NULL/NOT NULL declarations for column "equipment_id" of table "task"
SQL state: 42601
```

How can I maintain my data integrity while adding a Foreign key to my tables so that it works as expected? I thought you could have null references.

Comment: Your code [seems to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=acf96e2e73c01cca746986bc3f5a288d). I am unsure what your actual issue is.

Comment: updated the reference to NULL

Comment: `serial` implies `NOT NULL` but it's the wrong choice for `task.equipment_id` to begin with (see Gordon's answer)

Answer (score 1):

You have a potential modeling issue: "Task needs some Equipment" as stated. But does "some" actually mean "one",  Can a Task require 2 or more Equipment? If so and assuming an Equipment can be needed by more that 1 task, you need a resolution table (Task_Equipment perhaps) to resolve the many-to-many this represents. So then

```
create table equipment (
       id serial primary key
     , equipment_name varchar(80)
     );

create table task (
      id serial primary key
    , task_name varchar(80)
    ); 

create table task_equipment (
       task_id       int
     , equipment_id  int 
     , constraint    te_pk 
                     primary key (task_id, equipment_id)
     , constraint    te2task_fk 
                     foreign key (task_id)
                     references task(task_id)
     , constraint    te2equipment_fk 
                     foreign key (equipment_id)
                     references equipment(equipment_id)  
     );
```

And I agree if your version has it use as identity instead of serial.

Answer (score 0):

`serial` is a data type that is really an integer.  So, you want:

```
create table task (
    id serial primary key,
    task_name varchar(80),
    equipment_id int references equipment(id) 
);
```

That said, Postgres now recommends using `int generated always as identity`.  This makes it clearer:

```
create table task (
    id int generated always as identity primary key,
    task_name varchar(80)
);

create table task (
    id int generated always as identity primary key,
    task_name varchar(80),
    equipment_id int references equipment(id) 
);
```

The reasons for preferring `generated always as identity` are technical.  But one effect is that the code is more consistent -- both the primary key and foreign key have the same explicit type.